AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Summary'
When running this code:
def scalar_summary(self, tag, value, step):
        """Log a scalar variable."""
        summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])
        self.writer.add_summary(summary, step)

I get the error message:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Summary'. Did you mean: 'summary'?
I am trying to run the code from https://github.com/InhwanBae/ENet-SAD_Pytorch/blob/master/utils/tensorboard.py on Google colabs. I am trying to train the ENet-SAD model using the CULane dataset.

From the source code, tensorflow v2.2.3 is the last version that contains tf.Summary export
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.3/tensorflow/python/__init__.py#L199
The paper is from 2019, therefore I would suggest you to limit package versions before 2019 to avoid possible issues.
